# while on input by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a beginner learning javascript.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        $(this).closest('.number').val(i)
        i++;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn">Sort</div>

<input type="text" class="number" data-id="1" value="1">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="5" value="5">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="4" value="4">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="3" value="2">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="2" value="3">
```

My Output:

```
<div class="btn">Sort</div>

<input type="text" class="number" data-id="1" value="1">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="5" value="2">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="4" value="3">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="3" value="4">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="2" value="5">
```

when click on `.btn`,it `all value sort:1,2,3,4,5` is not saved.
Help me solve this problem.

Comment: The `.closest()` method looks *up* the DOM from the starting point, which in this case is your `<div>`.  It will find none of the `<input>` elements. Even if it did, it would always find the same one on each iteration.

Comment: FYI: If you need a button use a `<button>` element, it improves accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the "button" to update the values of the `input` elements, in order from 1-5?

For starters, you're misunderstanding that [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) does.  It looks for the "closest" matching element *up the DOM hierarchy*.  The `.number` elements are not parents/ancestors of the `.btn` element, so none of them will match.

You can find the `.number` elements with simply: `$('.number')`

Then you can use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over those elements.  The first argument to the callback is the *index* of that element in the resulting collection.  It's zero-based, so just add `1` to it.  For example:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $('.number').each(function(i) {
    $(this).val(i + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Sort</div>

<input type="text" class="number" data-id="1" value="1">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="5" value="5">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="4" value="4">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="3" value="2">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="2" value="3">
```

Comment: That's not what *sorting* means

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method over looping with `.each` is to pass a callback function to [`.val`](https://api.jquery.com/val/), the first argument to which is the index.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', () => $('.number').val(i => i + 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Sort</div>
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="1" value="1">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="5" value="5">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="4" value="4">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="3" value="2">
<input type="text" class="number" data-id="2" value="3">
```